# Why is the option for Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp) missing in Visual Studios?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to write a program in C++ to run on windows xp machines, but when I go to set the tool set to Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp) it is missing.  All that I have is Visual Studio 2012 (v110).  Does anyone know how to get the other options here?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280956/how-to-use-msbuild-to-target-v110-platform-toolset) might help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to install an update, Windows XP support wasn't available in the initial release of VS 2012. Go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates and install all available updates.

Comment: Thank you, trying this now.  I figured since i Just installed from Microsoft's website yesterday I would be good to go, but I was wrong.

Comment: Thank you! This got me working.  Though it never did give me the dropdown, I had to type the option in.

Comment: @JoelLewis: Happens with all Microsoft products. You download the most recent installer from their website - and then, immediately after the installation, you spend hours installing hundreds of updates.