# Why is the option for Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp) missing in Update 4?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

(not a duplicate of [Why is the option for Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp) missing in Visual Studios?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19278446/432818))

According to Help->About, I have Visual Studio Premium 2012 Update 4 installed. I don't have the v110_xp toolkit option available. Any ideas how I might get it?

Tools->Extensions and Updates->Updates is not an option as the machine can't see the Internet.

Comment: Well, of course it is available, there is no install option to intentionally leave it out.  If it is missing then the install didn't go well.  Spin the wheel of fortune and reinstall.  Pay attention to the dd*.log files in your TEMP directory if that didn't help.

Comment: I have VS2012 Update 4 and have no problems with the XP platform toolset. Did you ever have it available?

Comment: I don't know if it has ever been available, haven't needed it before. It is definitely not there now. Tried a repair install, no change. I'll try a full uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Hans, any idea what I might be looking for in 155MB of log files?