# Unable to Publish SQL Server 2014 database using Web Deploy in VS 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2013, web-deployment

Its been quite sometime that I am trying to publish the data base for my website using webdeploy in VS 2013 but I keep getting the following error:

> Web deployment task failed. (Could not generate deployment script.
>   Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.

I have tried installing the new updates. I am making sure that the local server is running during deployment. I have made sure that I enter the full server name rather than a dot. I have literally done everything that I could think of but to no avail.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to VisualStudioVersion environment variable, which needs to be set to VisualStudioVersion=11.0 or VisualStudioVersion=12.0 to support SQL Server 2014. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334802/why-does-the-sqlpublish-target-fail-for-a-sql-server-2014-database-project), also here is the info [how to target the VisualStudioVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280956/how-to-use-msbuild-to-target-v110-platform-toolset).

Comment: I have checked my batch file, the environment variable is set to 12.0